# Performance of System.IO.File vs System.IO.FileStream

Tags: c#, file, filestream

I tried to use `File` class and `FileStream` class to read data from a large file or write a large amount of data into a file.

Suppose I use C# in Visual Studio 2010. Which class offers me a better performance and why?

Comment: Did you tried both? http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 3):

The best way to find out is to build some sample applications using both, and test it based on your input data. That way you will have scientific evidence to base your decision on. Read Eric Lippert's blog [post](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) as Soner Gönül suggested in the comments.

> If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the
>   faster then race your horses. Don't write short descriptions of the
>   horses, post them on the Internet, and ask random strangers to guess
>   which is faster! Even if by sheer chance you got an accurate answer,
>   how would you have any confidence in its accuracy? You can easily and
>   accurately discover which of two programs is faster by running both
>   yourself and measuring them with a stopwatch. - Eric Lippert

Answer (score 3):

A `FileStream` is the only way to do (normal) file IO. Any method in the `File` class uses a `FileStream` to access the files.

So, using `FileStream` will get you closest to the file system, but the methods in the `File` class doesn't add much overhead so you will only be able to outperform them if you have some special knowledge of the actual files that you want to work with that lets you optimise the file access in some way.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using LARGE files, FileStream is the only way to go - using File will read the entire file into memory.  While using FileStream will allow you to read/write parts of the file.  That being said, try File first (Its much easier to use) and see if it performs ok.